# MYSQLI fetch_array not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to figure out why my mysqli query is not returning all the rows. For some reason it returns 3 results when there are 4 in the database. It is completely skipping the first record in the database. Here is my query.

```
$results = "SELECT * FROM `results` LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($results);
if ($result) { 
?>
    <div id="tableResults">
    <div class="row1 bg">Predicted Sex</div>
    <div class="row2 bg">Suggested Baby Boy Name</div>  
    <div class="row3 bg">Suggested Baby Girl Name</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>

<?php
    /* fetch object array */
    $i = 0;
    $count = count($result->fetch_array());
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
?>
        <div class="row1 <?php if (!$i == $count - 1) { echo 'customborder'; } ?>"><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></div> 
        <div class="row2 <?php if (!$i == $count - 1) { echo 'customborder'; } ?>"><?php echo $row['boy_name']; ?></div>
        <div class="row3 <?php if (!$i == $count - 1) { echo 'customborder'; } ?>"><?php echo $row['girl_name']; ?></div>
<?php
    $i++;
    } 
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You call fetch_array before calling it in your while loop.  This effectively loses one of your rows.

Comment: Well, you call `$result->fetch_array()` before retrieving the result inside the `while` condition. That retrieves the first row which is why you run into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments `$count = count($result->fetch_array());` this will not work as expected and makes you lose one row (as it has been fetched). Instead you can use [`num_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) like the following

```
$count = $result->num_rows;
while ($row= $result->fetch_array()) {
    //...
}
```

---

To go into detail, when you read the manual on [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array), you'll find this part

> `mysqli_result::fetch_array` -- `mysqli_fetch_array` — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

A result row (in words: **one**) will be fetched any time this function is called. So currently your code is similar to:

```
fetch one row -> do nothing with it
while:
    fetch one row -> display it
```